# Solving linear program using non-linear optimzation using scipy optimize?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I need to solve a linear programming problem in python and have only libraries from numpy stack which essentially includes scipy.optimize since as far as I understand linear program is a constrained optimization problem is it justified to use "SLSQP" from scipy.optimize.Or does it lead to grossly inefficient solution?

Comment: How big is your LP? and also is it really linear (no integer variables?) if it's a tiny LP and you have a good reason not to use GLPK, CBC, or a commercial solver you might get away with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,yes it is a standard LP problem.Its a pruning problem.You have two vectors v1,v2 and you have a parameter vector 'x'.Now,find the point 'x' such that the difference in dot product x.v1-x.v2 is minimum.The constraints being sum(x)=1 and x[i]>=0 for all i.

Comment: How big is your decision vector?